# Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '_' looking for beginning of value

Tags: mongodb, powershell, csv, mongoimport

I have been to trying to import a csv file in Mongo DB server using 'mongoimport' cmd. The error was  "invalid character '_' looking for beginning of value ".

When I opened the csv file, invalid character '_' was at the beginning of the file, and when I tried to removed that and try to run the command again its showing the same error again with a new character as invalid, i.e the first letter of the file.
What's the reason for error, is it the csv file or the command format, and how to solve it ..?
This is the command I tried to run :
" mongoimport --db mongo_practice --collection people --file people.csv"

I am using MongoDB Version 6.0 and running the command on windows powershell

Can anyone please clarify ??

Comment: please put the csv file too.

Comment: If this is PowerShell than you can skip first line using : Select-String with -Pattern "^[^_]" which is the beginning of the line and then NOT '_'

Comment: Could be an encoding problem. Try to save the input csv file in UTF8 encoding